# How to get minimum and maximum values of a dynamic integer array?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dynamic-arrays

How can I find out the minimum and maximum values of a certain dynamic array defined by `array of Integer` ?

ex:

```
Y: array of integer;
```

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way is to use the built-in functions that perform this service. They are called [`MinIntValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.MinIntValue) and [`MaxIntValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.MaxIntValue) and can be found in the Math unit.

```
uses
  Math;
....
TheMin := MinIntValue(TheArray);
TheMax := MaxIntValue(TheArray);
```

Comment: Im am using a dynamic array. Is there any function that will help me process it because I am getting an incompatible types error

Comment: The functions that I describe work with dynamic arrays of integer. What type are your arrays?

Comment: I am working with a dynamic array of a separate object. So i get the error 'Incompatible types Integer and TObject'

Comment: That's a different question. I answered your question about arrays of integers.

Answer (score 11):

There are overloaded functions for this in the unit Math:

```
function MinValue(const Data: array of Single): Single; overload;
function MinValue(const Data: array of Double): Double; overload;
function MinValue(const Data: array of Extended): Extended; overload;
function MinIntValue(const Data: array of Integer): Integer;

function MaxValue(const Data: array of Single): Single; overload;
function MaxValue(const Data: array of Double): Double; overload;
function MaxValue(const Data: array of Extended): Extended; overload;
function MaxIntValue(const Data: array of Integer): Integer;
```

since you are using integers you should use MinIntValue and MaxIntValue

Comment: Im am using a dynamic array. Is there any function that will help me process it because I am getting an incompatible types error

Answer (score 5):

You have to loop through the array, looking for the desired values, eg:

```
function TMyClass.GetMinValue: Integer;
var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  Result := MyArray[Low(MyArray)];
  for Idx := Low(MyArray)+1 to High(MyArray) do
  begin
    if MyArray[Idx] < Result then
      Result := MyArray[Idx];
  end;
end;

function TMyClass.GetMaxValue: Integer;
var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  Result := MyArray[Low(MyArray)];
  for Idx := Low(MyArray)+1 to High(MyArray) do
  begin
    if MyArray[Idx] > Result then
      Result := MyArray[Idx];
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The mentioned `MinIntValue` and `MaxIntValue` functions are in Delphi 7 already, so even though you're right, you don't have to use this code, but use those functions.

Comment: The nice thing about this approach is that it can be combined into a single function that returns both, if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in a single loop...

```
function ArrayValRange( somearray: array of integer; var minval: integer; var maxval: integer): boolean;
var
   i: integer;
begin
  result := false;
  if length( somearray) < 1 then
      exit;
  result := true;

  maxval = somearray[ Low(somearray)];
  minval = maxval;

  for i := Low(somearray)+1 to High(somearray) do
  begin
    if somearray[i] > maxval then
      maxval := somearray[i];

    if somearray[i] < minval then
      minval := somearray[i];

  end;
end;
```

then

```
if ArrayValRange( myarray, min, max) then
begin
   //do your thing
end;
```

Comment: Any performance gain is probably lost by the copy of the array that is made. Make it const.